# Show Camera in two window at the same time

Tags: qt, camera, qml

My main window is creating another window displayed on a second screen

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow

    property var customerUi

    Component.onCompleted: {
        customerUi = customerWindow.createObject()
        if (ScreenManager.screenCount() > 1)
            ScreenManager.setScreen(customerUi, 1)
    }
}
```

Both window need to display a video of the same camera (it is actually a live feed from a usb adaptor, but it works the same)

```
Camera {
    id: camera
    deviceId: "my_device"
}

VideoOutput {
    source: camera
}
```

It works fine in one window, but the second window never show the video. I guess because the Camera handle cannot be grabbed by two interface at the same time (or something like that)

I tried creating only one Camera, and two VideoOutput using the same source but it doesn't work either.

I  tried to duplicate the view using a ShaderEffect, but

```
ShaderEffectSource: sourceItem and ShaderEffectSource must both be children of the same window
```

How can I display the video on both window at the same time ?

EDIT :

Apparently it was possible in Qt 5.3 using ShaderEffectSource
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43117

But I'm need to make it work with Qt 5.5.1

EDIT 2 :

Duplicating the Video in the same window works fine using ShaderEffectSource, the problem is only to put it in another window.

Comment: Duplication video output currently not supported - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46076

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to copy the view somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve the issue :

I create a third `Window` wide enough to cover both screen, and duplicate the window using `ShaderEffectSource`.

This only works because my two Windows are fullscreen on each screen

I'm still looking for an actual solution to the problem, though.

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution with two windows, did you ever figure out something ?

Comment: It's been a while, I don't remember the exact solution but I think we did something directly on the Operating System running the software, maybe we created a virtual camera that was duplicating the feed from the first.

If you have control over the execution env and it is linux you could have a look at v4l2 (video for linux 2)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Item::grabToImage(callback, targetSize)` method to fill static `Image` with in-memory saved data from `source`. You'll need 1/60 timer for that also. But I it's quite CPU expensive I believe, so beware :)

Answer (score -1):

Create two Window items in one main.qml file:

```js
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Item {
    Window {
        title: qsTr("Hello World")
        objectName: "wnd1"
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
    }

    Window {
        title: qsTr("Hello World 2")
        objectName: "wnd2"
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
    }
}
```

Then, load it from your main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

You should be able to reuse components easily if it's within the same QML file.

Comment: I tried your answer and get the problem I expected : you cannot use ShaderEffectSource with a sourceItem living in another Window, even if they are declared in the same QML file

Comment: Did you try creating two VideoOutput with the same Camera as source attribute? No need for a ShaderEffectSource in order to achieve what you described.